# Get Header name

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hello I am a bit lost with the control Templates, I have an expander and some control-styles that apply onto the Expander.
So the idea is to let the User insert the header

```
<Expander Name="MyExpanderExpander"  Style="{StaticResource MyExpanderNewGeneration}" Header="UserChoice" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="210">
```

So now the Style : MyExpanderNewGeneration should get the header Name : UserChoic
 The ToggleButton has to get the Header Name : UserChoice and here is my problem ..but how to do it?

my Style applying is

```
    <Style TargetType="Expander" x:Key="MyExpanderNewGeneration" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseControlStyle}" >
            <!--x:Key="GroupBoxStyle"-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
                        <Grid>
                            <!--Grid Rows split the GroupBox into two areas -->
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!--Header area-->
                            <Border Name="HeaderArea"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Background="Transparent"

      BorderBrush="Transparent"
      BorderThickness="1"
      CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" >
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" 

                           Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Margin="0,0,0,0"  
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"                                                                
                          Template="{StaticResource TestToggleButton}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
                                </ToggleButton>
```

Herer I want to get the UserChoice Name.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="TestToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Foreground="White" Width="300" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Something={HEADER???}
```

> 

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting `Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"` in your `ExpanderButton`, you will need to bind to the `Content` property inside your `TestToggleButton` style's control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TestToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label 
            ...
            Content={TemplateBinding Content} />
        ...
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: hey keithernet, I have tried it, and it didn't worked. Do you have an another Idea?